# loop though which I need to get/add 0's in the start

Tags: python

I have an array list values as below

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array([5.93442446e-01, 2.41275693e-01, 9.80953766e-02, 3.98826039e-02,
       1.62150567e-02, 6.59255008e-03, 2.68033084e-03, 1.08974120e-03,
       4.43055708e-04, 1.80133009e-04, 7.32366160e-05, 2.97757861e-05])

data = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])
```

And using these array lists I have multiplied with data below

```
decayed_value = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    transformed_data = lst * data[i]
    decayed_value.append(np.int64(transformed_data))
```

If you see I have got the decayed_value but I want these values with 0's in the start as the data goes on.

Expected Output:

```
[array([59, 24,  9,  3,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 118,  48,  19,   7,   3,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 178,  72,  29,  11,   4,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 0, 237,  96,  39,  15,   6,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 296, 120,  49,  19,   8,   3,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       dtype=int64),
....
...
..
.]
```

I need to get 0's in the above way. How do I do this?

Comment: use the `i` in an nested loop, range over it and add `i` number of zeroes at start.

Comment: @ImanpalSingh Sorry, didn't get you. Could you write down the nested loop?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to manipulate the numpy array.

One way to do this would be to use numpy.insert option. Since you are looking to extract each value in data and multiply with the `lst` array, you can do it this way. I am sure there are more efficient ways to do it. This is a quick and dirty option for you to consider.

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([5.93442446e-01, 2.41275693e-01, 9.80953766e-02, 3.98826039e-02,
       1.62150567e-02, 6.59255008e-03, 2.68033084e-03, 1.08974120e-03,
       4.43055708e-04, 1.80133009e-04, 7.32366160e-05, 2.97757861e-05])
data = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])
     
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    lst_x = (lst * d).astype(int)
    if i > 0: 
        lst_x = np.insert(lst_x,0,[0,]*i)[:len(lst)]
    print (lst_x)
```

Output of this will be:

```
[ 59  24   9   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0 118  48  19   7   3   1   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0 178  72  29  11   4   1   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0 237  96  39  15   6   2   1   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0 296 120  49  19   8   3   1   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0 356 144  58  23   9   3   1]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0 415 168  68  27  11   4]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 474 193  78  31  12]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 534 217  88  35]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

If you want these to be stored into a list (`decayed_value`), then you can add this to your code:

```
decayed_value = []

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    lst_x = (lst * d).astype(int)
    if i > 0: 
        lst_x = np.insert(lst_x,0,[0,]*i)[:len(lst)]
    #print (lst_x)
    decayed_value.append(lst_x)

print (decayed_value)
```

Output of this will be:

```
[array([59,  24,   9,   3,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0, 118,  48,  19,   7,   3,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0, 178,  72,  29,  11,   4,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0, 237,  96,  39,  15,   6,   2,   1,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0, 296, 120,  49,  19,   8,   3,   1,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 356, 144,  58,  23,   9,   3,   1]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 415, 168,  68,  27,  11,   4]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 474, 193,  78,  31,  12]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 534, 217,  88,  35]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]), 
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])]
```

Comment: Do you think this is a good way to do it? Basically, I wanted to add these values after the above thing by doing [sum(i) for i in zip(*decayed_values)] which is my final output. Is there a better or simple way to do that or this is what it is?

Comment: I don't want my last values to disappear in the end though. Like if you see this array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 534, 217,  88,  35]) from above and my decayed value list same line array([534., 217.,  88.,  35.,  15.,   6.,   2.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0., 0.]), The 15,6,2,1,0,0,0,0 values got removed, which I do not intend to do.